# How to open the exact required screen of the flutter app from deep_link?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the uni_links package which creates a deep_link that when clicked opens exactly the screen I need. Now I am able to automatically open the app from the given link but it doesn't go to the exact screen I need, it just goes to the default page. I also use getX for state management if that helps. If the question is incorrect, please feel free to commend

The page needs to be opened from the link, new_password_page.dart

```
import 'package:darcy/app/global_widgets/base_button.dart';
import 'package:darcy/app/global_widgets/outline_textfield.dart';
import 'package:darcy/app/modules/forgot_password/forgot_controller_page.dart';
import 'package:darcy/routes/pages.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart';

import '../../../core/theme/app_theme.dart';

class NewPasswordPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ForgotController _homeController = Get.find<ForgotController>();
  NewPasswordPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newPassword = '';
    String confirmPassword = '';
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.base_background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('New Password'),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: AppTheme.transparent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                ),
                OutlinedTextField(
                  text: newPassword,
                  labelText: 'New password',
                  messageText: '',
                  onTextChange: (value) {
                    newPassword = value;
                  },
                  customIcon: Icons.password_rounded,
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                OutlinedTextField(
                  text: confirmPassword,
                  labelText: 'Confirm password',
                  messageText: '',
                  onTextChange: (value) {
                    confirmPassword = value;
                  },
                  customIcon: Icons.password_rounded,
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 32.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: BaseButton(
                      buttonText: 'confirm'.tr,
                      buttonColor: AppTheme.sign_in,
                      buttonFunction: () {
                        Get.toNamed(Routes.SUCCESS);
                      },
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

new_password_controller.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:darcy/app/data/network/services/user_api.dart';
import 'package:darcy/core/base_controller/base_controller.dart';
import 'package:darcy/routes/pages.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart';

class ForgotController extends GetxController with BaseController {
  var id = '';
  var email = '';
  StreamSubscription? sub;

  final UserApi _userApi = Get.find<UserApi>();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    initUniLinks();
  }

  Future<Null> initUniLinks() async {
    try {
      String? initialLink = await getInitialLink();

      // Parse the link and warn the user, if it is not correct,
      // but keep in mind it could be `null`.
    } on PlatformException {
      // Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed
      // return?
    }
  }

  void forgot() async {
    showLoading(message: 'Please wait...', barrierDismissible: false);
    final Email send_email = Email(
      body: 'Đây nè em trai http://flutterbooksample.com',
      subject: 'Link khôi phụn password',
      recipients: ['samnkse62331@fpt.edu.vn'],
      isHTML: false,
    );

    try {
      hideLoading();
      await FlutterEmailSender.send(send_email);
    } catch (e) {
      print("hàng: ${e}");
    }
    // await _userApi.forgot(email, int.parse(id)).then((value) {
    //   hideLoading();
    //   print(value.error);
    //   if (value.error != true) {
    //     Get.toNamed(Routes.RECOVERY);
    //   }
    // }).catchError((e) {
    //   handleErrorWithToast(e);
    // });
  }
}
```

method to open the app from link

```
Future<Null> initUniLinks() async {
    try {
      String? initialLink = await getInitialLink();

      // Parse the link and warn the user, if it is not correct,
      // but keep in mind it could be `null`.
    } on PlatformException {
      // Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed
      // return?
    }
  }
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:darcy/core/lang/localization_service.dart';
import 'package:darcy/core/storage/spref_helper.dart';
import 'package:darcy/core/theme/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:darcy/injector.dart';
import 'package:darcy/routes/pages.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //forced portrait orientation only
  await InitialBinding().setup();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then((_) {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Darcy',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      getPages: Pages.pages,
      initialRoute: Routes.SPLASH,
      initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: AppTheme.colorPrimarySwatch,
      ),
      locale:
          Get.find<SharedPreferencesHelper>().getDefaultLocaleFromLangCode(),
      fallbackLocale: LocalizationService.fallbackLocale,
      translations: LocalizationService(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use named routes.

Let's say your deep link is something like `https://my.app/new-password` and you have a named route in your app for this page called `new-password`, then on your function `initUnilinks`, you get the path of the URI and navigate to the route you want.

```
Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    try {
      Uri? initialLink = await getInitialLink();
      if (initalLink != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(initialLink.path);
      }
      
    } on PlatformException {
      // Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed
      // return?
    }
  }
```

I'm not familiar with getX, it might have something for routing that you could use.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, can you tell me where should I put the initUniLinks method in the app??? It seems that the variable initialLink is always null and cannot be forwarded to the specified page. I have added to my question the file main.dart, hope you can check it out

Comment: The app I'm working on now has two ways of listening to deep links, one is sitting at the highest, in my `App` widget which is the initial points of my widget tree, and it listens to `initialLink`. 

I've also integrated with Firebase dynamic links, and that is handled in the widget below my `App` one and is the one used most, as the other option is now legacy code for me.


If you are not getting anything, experiment moving it around in your widget tree, as high as possible

Comment: Now opening the required screen from the link was successful but it doesn't go back to the currently open app but instead it opens a new app and.

 For example, I have an app called Darcy, I forgot my password and need to send an email to the server to request a new password. An email will send a link to create a new password, which will lead the user to the screen to create a new password. 

But instead of it will lead the user to the new password generation screen of the open Darcy app, it will open a new Darcy app.